# Appengine permissions to change Joda time default time zone

Tags: java, google-app-engine, permissions, jodatime

I want to change default time zone so it's our local European/Prague - because I work with week/days boundaries.

But calling (I call it in filter bfore processing each request)

```
DateTimeZone.setDefault(DateTimeZone.forID(DateUtils.TIME_ZONE));
```

results into permissions excpetion. I don't think I cant accquire new permissions on appengien, what do I do?

TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone(DateUtils.TIME_ZONE)); works fine though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would simply avoid using the default time zone anywhere. Always pass the time zone in explicitly to whatever will be using it. That makes the code clearer, more robust in the face of system defaults changing, more robust in the face of requiring two time zones to be used in the same application, and means you don't need to work out *how* to change the system default on AppEngine.

(As an aside, in my port of Joda Time to .NET, although we *support* fetching the system time zone, we don't use it as the default *anywhere* in the code - you *have* to be explicit about what you want. The system default is the wrong choice in so many situations, it's a bad idea to use it by default IMO.)

Comment: In many situations I agree, but in my current situation I need whole application to work in specific time zone. It's a specification. I can put this consatnt everywhere in the code, but request filtering seems more configurable and maintainable

Comment: @Hurda: You can always wrap up the zone-sensitive operations that you use most commonly into helper methods. I think being explicit about everything is likely to work better than trying to change the AppEngine default time zone.